# Bash reading from a file to an associative array

Tags: arrays, bash, associative

I'm trying to write a script in bash using an associative array.
I have a file called `data`:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

The following script:

```
oldIFS=${IFS}
IFS=","

declare -A assoc
while read -a array
do 
  assoc["${array[0]}"]="${array[@]}"
done

for key in ${!assoc[@]}
do
  echo "${key} ---> ${assoc[${key}]}"
done 

IFS=${oldIFS}
```

gives me

```
a ---> a b c d e f

g ---> g h i j k l
```

I need my output to be:

```
a b ---> c d e f

g h ---> i j k l
```

Answer (score 17):

```
oldIFS=${IFS}
IFS=","

declare -A assoc
while read -r -a array
do 
  assoc["${array[0]} ${array[1]}"]="${array[@]:2}"
done < data

for key in "${!assoc[@]}"
do
  echo "${key} ---> ${assoc[${key}]}"
done

IFS=${oldIFS}
```

data:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
g,h,i,j,k,l
```

Output:

```
a b ---> c d e f
g h ---> i j k l
```

Uses [`Substring Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) here `${array[@]:2}` to get substring needed as the value of the `assoc` array. Also added `-r` to `read` to prevent backslash to act as an escape character.

Improved based on @gniourf_gniourf's suggestions:

```
declare -A assoc
while IFS=, read -r -a array
do 
    ((${#array[@]} >= 2)) || continue
    assoc["${array[@]:0:2}"]="${array[@]:2}"
done < data

for key in "${!assoc[@]}"
do
    echo "${key} ---> ${assoc[${key}]}"
done
```

Comment: You could add a few improvements: 1. Put `IFS=,` for the `read` command and not have to fiddle saving `IFS` and restoring it. 2. In the loop add `((${#array[@]}>=2)) || continue` or something similar to get rid of empty lines. 3. Write your assignment as `assoc["${array[@]::2}"]=${array[@]:2}`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf, Is `${array[@]::2}` form of `${parameter:offset:length}` with ommited `offset` and then the `offset` is assumed zero?